# What is the best way to create a dynamic email template that can be modified without changing code in C# .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, .net-4.5, email

I'm creating a web application that needs to send the user an email when an action is completed. In the email body, I'm required to inform the user the transaction details in their last action. I'm aware of how to send emails to a person and how to I could possibly add in the transaction details by hardcoding the message in a string. What I would like to know is, how can I make this email subject without hardcoding it by either making it in a JSON file or in my database so that changing the message in the email body does not require me to publish the application again.

Currently, my idea is to create a JSON file with the mail body in several keys and combine the key values into a string in the application. This is the JSON structure that I'm currently considering:

```
{
  "NewTransaction":{
    "EN":{
      "Greeting":"Dear ",
      "Introduction":"We found that a transaction was completed against your name on ",
      "Body1":". The following are some of your transaction details:",
      "Body2":"Kindly let us know if there is any discrepancy with this transaction"
    },
    "MY":""
  }
}
```

While trying to figure this out, I've found [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=razorengine) package that seems like it would be pretty helpful in creating the mail body.

Is there any other better way that perhaps I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SendGrid makes email templating super easy.  You might want to consider looking into services that have solved these issues already, and have the dedicated infrastructure in place

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! I'm going to test that one out and then check if the service fees can be justified with my stakeholders :) Still open to other suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every question that starts with "What is the best way to" is probably too broad or opinion-based.

In my vision, you could create a table (field name on the right, sample data on left)

> id: 1
>   from: @@sysadress@@
>   to: @@useremail@@
>   subject: Trnasaction completed
>   body: Here goes your html body filled with @@data@@
>   ... more fields as needed ...

see @@these things@@ - these would be your placeholders for dynamic text.

In your action table you will add a column, something like actionMessage and link it to `Message` table. Even better is to create `Action_Message` table.

`Id, ActionId, MessageId, ActionStatus`

This will allow to send different messages depending if your action failed, completed or postponed, or whatever.

So, this could be one way. But you will not likely to find "the best way". Every best way can be improved upon. But this will definitely achieve your main goal - change messages without recompilation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, I get it that the best way can be very subjective. But I wanted it to be broad so that I could get a variety of possible ways to better understand what might be the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) for the sending of the email.

To get the data, why don't you just use SQL, you can store the subject and content in fields that you can update on the fly.

Comment: This is the Laravel Way too. A view that can be parsed and sent as an e-mail

Comment: This library is great! Thanks. I will be using it in the future for sure. Right now, I've chosen to take the mail subject and body from a JSON file stored in the application directory because I feel like an API call or DB Call just for this might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
EmailTemplateHelper templateHelper = new EmailTemplateHelper( HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/template_path/EMAIL_TEMPLATE.template"));

Dictionary<string, string> replaceMapper = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    { "TAG1", emailInfo.name },
    { "TAG2", emailInfo.lastname}

};
mailMessage.Subject = templateHelper.GetSubject(replaceMapper);
mailMessage.Body = templateHelper.GetBody(replaceMapper);

mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

In your template file you should have %TAG1% where you want your data to go.

Comment: answers with no explanation considered low quality

Comment: Draugur, could you clarify where you got the "EmailTemplateHelper" class from?

Comment: is one random class name that you can create, but all you need is:
using System.Xml;
 XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
 document.Load(templateFilePath);

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task SendTaskStatusMail(string name, string adminMail)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Template\\adminmail.html");
 
    MailAddress to = new(adminMail);
    MailAddress from = new("xyz@gmail.com");
    MailMessage mailMessage = new(from, to)
        {
            Subject = "Task Status Update"
        };
    StreamReader reader = new(path);
    string body;
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    body = body.Replace("{{Name}}",name);
  );
    mailMessage.Body = body;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", apppassword);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add explanations and not only code !